# System.Net.WebException can not resolve google.com

Tags: c#, windows-8.1

Target platform: Windows 8.1

I have this simple code

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Diagnostics

public static async void DownloadFile(string url)
{
                HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
                WebResponse resp = await request.GetResponseAsync();
                System.IO.Stream stream =  resp.GetResponseStream();
                System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream);
                Debug.WriteLine("content:" + reader.ReadToEnd());
}
```

Now when I call this function like this

```
DownloadFile("https://www.google.com/");
```

It idles a bit and after ~10 seconds or so I get a System.Net.WebException in the GetResponseAsync-line

Additional information: The remote name could not be resolved: 'www.google.com'

This happens with every url. Yes my pc has internet and no I am not using proxies and I would suspect that google.com is not getting axed by the firewall.

Comment: You can try to flush the DNS cache - ipconfig /flushdns

Comment: That did not help, but thank you.

Comment: Perhaps your program is the one that's being blocked by the firewall... try adding an exception on your firewall rules for your program (remember to add the `*.vshost.exe`)

Comment: Are you running on the emulator or just local machine?

Comment: @fillobotto happens on both

Comment: @Josh Part going to try that

Answer (score 0):

Clearly it's an DNS problem. You may using "nslookup www.google.com" in the command line to check out is it works correctly.

Comment: The OP said it happens with every URL

Comment: Than check out the firewall, or maybe you can try on using IP address directly to see if it works properly.